# Order of variables in the stack (GCC)

Tags: c, variables, gcc, stack

When compiling C code in GCC, is there any way to guarantee that the stack variables will appear in the stack in the order i declare them (or in reversed order, doesn't matter to me)? I know this is possible via structs but I would rather not use them.

Comment: Why do you want this? And what's wrong with a `struct`?

Comment: I want to demonstrate a certain stack overflow issue when buffers and pointers and positioned in a certain way. And I do not want to use structs (rather, I can't) because some of the variables are declared in inline functions which are later called from the main routine.

Comment: Also, I looked at "Can a C compiler rearrange stack variables?" and basically the whole thread was like "yea, this can happen, unless you use structs" which as I said is something I wish not to do.

Comment: Nothing has changed in this regard in the meantime

Comment: You can't even guarantee that your variables are stored on the stack --- the compiler may keep them entirely in registers. Or it may store two variables in the stack slot. This is all totally up to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

The only way would be a struct which includes all variables in the order you like.

For local variables the compiler is free to reorder/reuse variables at any order it suits her. Some variables may not have a memory location at all, they live only in registers, others will be optimized away completely.

Comment: "...as it suits her." So your compiler is female. Interesting :)

Comment: @adelphus: well they also make ships female in English, which is equally weird for bystanders

Comment: @adelphus: I think I'm in love... with my compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adamant that you do not want to use a struct then you will have to allocate the stack memory yourself with `alloca()`. But then you will need to manage your local variables manually within that block of stack memory.

I would not recommend that you do this. Use a struct.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable approach is to direct gcc to produce assembly language output using `gcc -S`, and examine the assembly language output to find out which variables have been put where. If you compile without optimisations, the variables probably won't get removed or rearranged, and if you assign different values to each local variable it should be easy to spot each one.

I admit that this is not very high-tech. But if you want to be sure that gcc is generating code that works in a particular way, you will have to look at the code it generates...